# Javascript select and change content of element according to the value

Tags: javascript, html, select

I would like to display some text according to what we select. 
Here is my select options:

```
<select onchange=Change(this.value)>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>

<p></p>
```

And I would like to apply a function that insert a certain text into the p element according to what option is selected.
Here is the function:

```
Change(x){
if (x=="1"){$("p").innerHTML ="One cat"}
if (x=="2"){$("p").innerHTML ="Two cats"}
}
```

And here is a fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/tksbkmdj/2/

Answer (score 3):

A few things to notice here:

1- You need to declare the function `Change`

2- With jQuery you do not do `innerHtml`, but instead, `.html(newtext)`, for instance.

Here you go:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function Change(x) {
    if (x == "1") {
      $("p").html("One cat")
    }
    if (x == "2") {
      $("p").html("Two cats")
    }
  }
</script>

<select onchange=Change(this.value)>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>

<p>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jQuery you can simplify things greatly:

```js
function Change(x){
  if (x=="1"){
    $("p").text("One cat");
  }
  if (x=="2"){
    $("p").text("Two cats");
  }
}
  
$("select").change(function() {
  Change(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>

<p></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.
The `innerHTML` is for JavaScript
Try `text()`or `html()`

```
$("p").text("One Cat");
$("p").text("Two Cats");
```

Or

```
$("p").html("One Cat");
$("p").html("Two Cats");
```

Answer (score 0):

you have the following mistakes:

- no "function" before "Change"
- better to name it "change"
- $("p") return a jquery object, you should use "$('p')[0]" or "$('p').html"
- the function is not in the global scope, therefore you cannot call it like that

check this https:`enter code here`//jsfiddle.net/ftb0tmds/